# How to identify the pcie slot?

Tags: motherboard, pci

When booting from a usb stick i got the error message from

> pcieport: Slot (92): Power fault

How can I check which Hardware component or which pcieport this is on my mainboard?

I am using Windows 10

Comment: Where did you get that message? What are you booting from a USB stick?

Comment: This is not the "exact" error message, there is some more info like address etc, but it is hard to capture. I boot Ubuntu 16.04 Bionic Beaver from a USB Stick